# uninstall pd-extended on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall

Hi  i have wrongly removed the extra direcotry from pd-extended. now logicaly pd cant start up! How can i uninstall pd-extended on ubuntu 14.04 LTS completely in order to install it again? Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: How did you install it? Which version?

Comment: via the website instructions on:http://puredata.info/docs/faq/debian

Comment: it "was" pd-0.43.4(extended)

Comment: Just re-install it, no need to remove it first.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it via the `puredata` repository:

To uninstall and reinstall keeping your configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get remove pd-extended && sudo apt-get install pd-extended
```

To uninstall and reinstall without keeping your configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge pd-extended && sudo apt-get install pd-extended
```

Comment: thanks. i did sudo purge. now by the way if i run whereis pd-extended i get in terminal:pd-extended: /usr/lib/pd-extended.  Does it mean my system is still not completely clean from pd-extended? thank you

Comment: and how can i define the path where it should be installed by reinstalling pd extended? thank you

Comment: @amir The commands i posted both uninstall and reinstall it, so it has been reinstalled already in `/usr/lib/pd-extended`!